# How to Access a share folder from server using ASP.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm want to access a share folder from my computer to server. But for access a folder from server need to key in the username and password. The below code is shows how could i commend for work it. But the issues is, it cannot function, it shows error

> "An exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred
>   in System.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information:
>   The network path was not found"

I'm already use google and search about it. But i could not find a specific solution for solve it. Please help me. I'm really need yours help...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = "admim";
            string pwrd = "admin321";
            {
                Process.Start(@"\\192.168.4.18\" + username + pwrd + "iso documents");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Accessing a share folder from your computer does not require asp.net. You just need Windows Explorer and network connectivity. To me it looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: Yes. But recently i'm doing a project in web application. I add a link button for access the server 192.168.4.18 sub-folder. If i click the link button, it directly connect or access the server. But the problem is, i do no how to add the username and password into the code. Can u help me please...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. I hope someone else will.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"c:\temp");
```

Comment: Do you want the list the files in the browser ?

Comment: Actually yes. But i need to open only one folder in server 192.168.4.18 which is "iso document" file. The problem is, i cannot directly access the server using the "Process" code. It was shows the error were i mentioned. Can you help me please...

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43091/Connect-to-a-UNC-Path-with-Credentials) this help you access a folder with credentials

Answer (score 0):

To access IUSR_WEBSERVER must have right to access
You can add following config

```
<system.web> <identity impersonate="true" userName="IUSR_WEBSERVER" password="password" /> </system.web>
```

Refer to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19830/How-to-Access-Network-Files-using-asp-net

Comment: Hi, the link were you give is only for edit the iis. Is that i m need to edit anything in program. It is because after i edit the iis, it still cannot function. Please help me...